# kubernetes dns lookup of microservice

Tags: dns, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

i have a question on the kubernetes DNS lookup, if i am using in my services deployment "dns" instead of "env",

Can my microservice using another microservices in the cluster get the dns names of all the microservices?

I get this piece of code, if I use `env` then I get the the info of host from env. but if I am using `dns` what format and how do I get the dns names, is there a DNS object I can query on the client side?

```
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) === true) {
  $host = 'redis-master';
if (getenv('GET_HOSTS_FROM') == 'env') {
  $host = getenv('REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST');
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-samples/blob/master/guestbook/php-redis/guestbook.php

If someone has examples (preferably nodejs), I can dig into that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off this is [documented throughly](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#supported-dns-schema). In any case if you want to query DNS to find out where things are running you can do so if you know the service name by pointing at:

```
my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Additionally, if you also want to abstract port numbers and are OK with knowing a port name you can query SRV records and get both port numbers as well as CNAME:

```
_my-port-name._my-port-protocol.my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

For your specific example this would be something like (assuming default namespace):

```
_redis-client._tcp.redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Querying SRV records is more reliable than depending on environment variables because if during the lifetime of the pod, an external service changes location, environment variables can't be re-injected, but re-querying DNS records will yield updated results.

Comment: Hi. How do you perform a SRV look up to query for the ports?

Comment: @EugeneR.Wang "dig" is a good tool to test it out manually, but presumably this would be done through some sort of other system. OP was using php so presumably something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php