# How to Perform a SRV Look up in Kubernetes to use the port to perfom service call

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, srv

[From this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079714/kubernetes-dns-lookup-of-microservice) I know that, a SRV look up can be performed to get the port of the kubernetes service. But exactly how do I perform that? How do I put it in my yml file? and when I do NSlook up

```
/ # nslookup  _main._tcp.account-service -type=srv
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
_main._tcp.account-service.default.svc.cluster.local    canonical name = account-service.default.svc.cluster.local.
Name:   account-service.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.103.238.155
```

I cannot see port either. The main port is pointing to 8082 btw.

Comment: Could you add information, what are you going to reach with such manipulations?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I am trying to reach a service on my kubernetes cluster. The idea is that I can look up its port to know where I should connect to.

Comment: When you define a Service, you describe its name and Ports in definition of it in yaml file for example

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Yes, I have the ports and name defined in my yaml file

Comment: Could you post your configuration of service?